# jQuery .each get index of items

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

The array fetched has a key and value for each item but I want to get a simple index for each value ie 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 etc which currently is not what the key gives (and nor do I want it to). Using `index` also does not seem to work.

```
$.getJSON( "filepath/current.json", function(data) {
  var items = [];
  $.each( data, function(key,val) {
    items.push( "<p id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</p>" );
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you give a sample of the file you are parsing?

Comment: What is `key` currently giving you?

Comment: Key gives some number gradually increasing in value like 66, 69, 87 etc and the value is text. That's what is in the json file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `objects` jQuery `each` doesn't support for an `index` parameter. But you can create an `index` for your own without any problems. **;)**

```js
var data = {
    one: "ONE",
    two: "TWO",
    three: "THREE"
  },
  items = [];

//Use a simple counter ;)

(function() {
  var i = 0;
  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    items.push("<p id='" + i + "'>" + val + "</p>");
    i++;
  });
})();

console.log(items);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var data = ["aa", "bb", "cc"];
var items = data.map((val, index) => "<p id='" + index + "'>" + val + "</p>");
console.log(items);
```

And it even cleaner with ECMAScrpt6 template litteral:

```js
var data = ["aa", "bb", "cc"];
var items = data.map((val, index) => `<p id='${index}'>${val}</p>`);
console.log(items);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getJSON( "filepath/current.json", function(data) {
  var items = [];
  for(key in data) {
      var insert_key=parseInt(key)||0;
      items.push( "<p id='" + insert_key + "'>" + data[key] + "</p>" );
  }        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `key` property is literally the index. If the `key` isn't a numeric index then your data is not an array but an object.

Your choices are:

a) rethink and redesign the solution. What are you going to use 0, 1, 2 etc for? Can it be replaced?

b) introduce a variable outside the `each` scope and manually increment it inside the scope. If you need to access the `val` later using the numeral index, you should map that `data` object to an array of objects containing only `key` and `val` properties.

Comment: Isn't there a numerical index based on the number of elements regardless of what the key is set to? Surely even if the key is "hello" and the value is "goodbye" it should still be known that the index of this element is 0 since it is the first one in the list? I assumed that value would always be accessible.

Comment: For arrays, yes. All arrays in javascript have numerical indexes.
However, no objects do. Any non-numerical index key adds property to an object, e.g. `var a =[]; a['prop']=1;` adds property with value 1, equivalently to `a.prop = 1`. Technically an array is an object, so this is correct, however `length` of that `a` array is still 0. Reverse won't work though - `var b = {}; b[0]='test'];`, `length` will be undefined. One more thing, due to how values are coerced, `array['1']` is still numerical index, even though you pass a string.